# Проблема Ruby на windows 10

Tags: windows, ruby

Установил **Ruby**, проверка `ruby -v`
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

проверка `gem -v`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        15: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
        14: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
        13: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1388:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1388:in `require'
        11: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:27:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
         9: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:96:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
         8: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:86:in `mingw_bin_path'
         7: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:73:in `msys_path'
         6: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:48:in `iterate_msys_paths'
         5: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:542:in `open'
         4: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:435:in `open'
         3: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:49:in `block in iterate_msys_paths'
         2: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:611:in `each_key'
         1: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:910:in `export_string'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:910:in `encode': U+00B5 to IBM866 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM866 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

цель - установить **Jekyll** на Windows 10
Что не так , подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Судя по трейсу, это проблема со свежим RubyInstaller. Стоит послать им в форме багрепорта. А пока обратите внимание на [рекомендации в правой колонке](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

Comment: Рекомендации -- тема. Пару дней назад решил поиграть с руби и скачал последнюю версию (`Ruby+Devkit 2.5.1-1 (x64)`), но при запуске стандартных рельс возникла проблема с sqlite гемом. Проблему решил когда поставил рекомендованную версию (`Ruby+Devkit 2.4.4-1 (x64) `)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с кодировкой - скорее всего дело в mingw32, попробуй установить с помощью [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby) или (если есть такая возможность в Windows) с помощью [rvm](https://rvm.io)
.